# Unable to connect to IS admin page from browser but can connect from designer

Tags: webmethods

I am not able to access WM 10.0 IS admin page http://localhost:6666 from web browser but I can access WM port 6666 from designer.

There is no specific error has shown in server log for trouble shooting the issue.

Comment: btw, I tried to access the IS admin page with the URL, http://localhost:6666/WmRoot/ but no use.

Answer (score 1):

The issue is resolved by including the property "--explicitly-allowed-ports=6666" to my chrome browser which is restricting the port.